# Clico em link e aparece o link do meu blog + o link que deveria abrir sozinho / Blogger

Tags: link, blogger

Tenho um blog no Blogger e quando clico em um link, aparece o link do meu blog + o link que deveria abrir, ficando assim:
https://www.vidadecomissaria.com.br/www.flymundo.com.br

Deveria abrir apenas o segundo link em uma nova aba, mas abre dessa forma aí.

O código é este:

```
<div class="quart cand" data-scroll-reveal="enter right and move 50px">
    <i class="fa fa-heart" />
    <b>Fly Mundo</b>
    <pre>Nossa agência de viagens</pre>
    <hr/>
    <p>Super recomendamos o serviço da FM, que vai desde seguro viagem até venda de passagens aéreas promocionais!</p>
    <em>E o atendimento é incrível!</em>
    <a class="touch" href="www.flymundo.com.br">VER MAIS</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Precisa colocar o protocolo no link `http` ou `https`, no seu caso seria algo como `http://www.flymundo.com.br`

Sem o `http` o html interpreta como um link relativo a URL atual.

Comment: Exatamente isso!

Answer (score 0):

Exatamente como disse o Neuber Oliveira.

O que você precisa fazer é substituir a linha:

```
<a class="touch" href="www.flymundo.com.br">VER MAIS</a>
```

por:

```
<a class="touch" href="http://www.flymundo.com.br">VER MAIS</a>
```